# How can I upgrade my website project to use the latest Telerik download?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, versioning

I'm trying to get a VB ASP.NET website (for which I was given the code) running in VS 2010. It uses telerik controls. I downloaded and installed the latest version of Telerik ("RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX v. 2016.1.225.0")

When I open the project in VS 2010, though, and open the Toolbox, it shows as Telerik control categories, "Telerik AJAX Controls [Bla] 2012 Q1 NET 35"

I would expect to see "... 2016.1.225.0" or "... 2016 Q1 NET 35" instead.

I don't know if having the older version of the controls is the problem or not (the developer who sent me the code is using an old version, too).

But I'm getting tons of compiler messages (the first one of the 123 showing, in fact, is "*Maximum number of errors has been exceeded*"), and I wonder if this version mismatch is the, or one of the, culprits. After that, there are several "*Type 'SQLServer' is not defined*" errors (among others) appear.

So should I upgrade my project to use the latest Telerik download, and if so, how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete and re-add the reference to the new version.  Every time you upgrade, there can be an issue of compatibility issues; I've been a long time user of Telerik and we occassionally get errors after upgrading.  Since youre version is about 4 years different, the best way is probably to just add the new reference and fix all of the compile and runtime errors...

I assume that the real reason for the errors you are getting is possibly other supporting DLL's not being installed on your machine (GAC references) that are on that developer's machine.  For instance, SQLServer errors would probably be referring to one of the Microsoft SQL Server type libraries...  It doesn't hurt to upgrade to the latest if you have the time, but that might not solve all the problems you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

In the visual  studio  menu  bar we have  telerik menue in that go  to  "upgrade" .  in the wizard it will  show the latest  telerik  reporting dll  you  have and will  update it .

Comment: I have the latest, that's what the problem is - mismatch between what the legacy code uses and what I'm trying to use.